# erase from list using JSON reply, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this list of items, and I have a button at the bottom for deleting some of them according to their checkboxes.
I also got a response from a jQuery get() with the elements that represent the new list.
So, the rest need to be removed.
This is how my list is built :

```
<table style="float:left;width:100%">
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <div>
            <td ?>;
                <input type="checkbox" name="item_<?php echo $item['NAME'];?>" value="<?php echo $item['ID'];?>" />
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

I use the get() function and get the following reply in json.

```
[{"ID":"2","EMAIL":"xxxxx@hotmail.com","DATETIME":"2011-12-12 03:20:01"},{"ID":"4","EMAIL":"xxxxx@gmail.com","DATETIME":"2011-10-09 01:15:22"}"]
```

All I want to do now is simply eliminate the correspoding  where the input value (which is the json's ID) is NOT in the json reply.

Any ideas how to do this with jQuery ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this. I kind of like going through your json response, flagging those that are confirmed, delete those unconfirmed, and remove the confirmed flag. e.g.

```
var json = [{'id':'2','email':... }];

// first, flag what we DO have
$.each(json,function(n,r){
  var $i = $(':input[value="' + r.ID + '"]');
  if ($i.length > 0){
    $i.addClass('ajax-confirmed');
  }
});
// delete what hasn't been flagged
$(':input:not(.ajax-confirmed)').each(function(m,r){
  var $row = $(r).closest('tr');
  $row.remove();
});
// then remove the flag (cleanup)
$(':input.ajax-confirmed').removeClass('ajax-confirmed');
```

Fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/v9paf/ (Or if you want to feel like you're deleting it... http://jsfiddle.net/v9paf/1/)

Comment: PS, a `<div>` tag has no place being between a `<tr>` and a `<td>`--I think you need to reverse the `<div>`/`<td>` spots...

Comment: I have more elemnts inside that tr, (I simplified the table for readablility). I was trying to make these elements show one on top of the other, any suggestions ?

Comment: For some reason it is erasing all the rows.

Comment: @Ted: Do you have a webpage up that I can see it on? Or can you paste what you have (maybe create your own fiddle?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9vYDe/1/ This is actual code from the site. and it doesn't work on jsFiddle either

Comment: @Ted: Once again, the `<div>` can **not** be between `<tr>` and `<td>`. I know you are only providing a snippet, but the page must follow html standards. Second, once I made jsFiddle include jQuery (drop-down on the left of the site where **MooTools** is shown currently) the page [worked fine](http://jsfiddle.net/9vYDe/2/).

Comment: yeah, for me too. For some reason it is eliminating all those <tr> tags. These checkbox inputs are the only ones in the form, your code seems to do the job on jsFiddle, but seems to erase all my <tr>s on the form. How can I go about debugging this ?